# Show prompt for HMS Core upgrade

Tags: huawei-developers, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

I used `getIapClient(Context context)` in my app for object instantiation. The app could not work well with devices with older versions of HMS core.

How to make the app show a prompt for HMS core upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use activity:

```
getIapClient(Activity activity)
```

instead of context when calling this method.

More details on [Huawei developer site](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/iap-0000001050137603-V5)

Comment: Very straightforward and accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please use  `public static IapClient getIapClient(Activity activity)`

As @Zinna said, the [getIapClient(Activity activity)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/iap-0000001050137603-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001063038261__section428943118437) method is recommended for your app to obtain an [IapClient](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/iapclient-0000001050137587-V5) instance. When the input parameter is not of the **Activity** type, if the HMS Core (APK) version is earlier than that requested for calling the APIs of IAP, the IAP SDK returns only the error code 907135003 and cannot display the upgrade wizard page.

If you call relevant APIs through an activity, the HMS Core SDK will automatically install or update HMS Core (APK), and you do not need to take any other actions.
Please refer to the docs [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/iap-0000001050137603-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001063038261__section14585204104416).

2. Please add the following metadata to the **application** block in **AndroidManifest.xml**: (to prompt a user to install or update HMS Core (APK) when the user uses your app on a device where HMS Core (APK) is not installed or is in an unsupported version)

```
<application ...>
    <meta-data     
       android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.channel.androidMarket"  
       android:value="false" />
    ...
</application>
```

About Configuring Metadata, please refer to [the docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/integrating-sdk-0000001050035023#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001063956052__section12843151332713).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details.

Comment: this meta data was the part that I was missing, after adding that I am getting the hms update dialog! Thanks